# Cross tab variable in javascript without server interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a chat system and got a question that I would like to ask you.

I dont think this is possible but since I see similar behaviour in some websites, I would like to know How to access a variable defined/modified in an other tab? I mean I don't want to send it to a server. How to do something like

```
  var myvalue=getValueInAvailableTab(varName);
```

If it is not possible, how does facebook know if the chat dialog has been closed in another tab? Do they post this event on their server and then retrieve it?

I am sorry I am not stealing behaviours but this is a best example to explain what I want to do.

Comment: In some cases you may use `opener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most circumstances, the answer to your question is that you cannot access a Javascript variable in another tab. There are other ways to pass data between tabs, however:

- You may create a browser extension that has the functionality that you want. Though different browser frameworks have different limitations upon accessing the code of pages that are open.
- If the windows are guaranteed to be opened by the same parent window, you may use `window.parent` or `window.opener`
- If both tabs are from the same origin site, you may have one tab store the value in the cookie, and have the other tab retrieve that value.

These are all ways in which you may accomplish what you need without server interaction. I'm not sure what method Facebook uses, however.

Comment: Similar but potentially easier than using cookies, you can use local storage or session storage

Comment: Absolutely correct. At the time of this answer, local storage did not have as much support as it does currently. I shall take the time to update with this now widely supported option.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the browser tabs are from the same domain, you can keep track of them by keeping a reference to the return value of `window.open(...)`:

```
var wins = {};
wins.someTab = window.open(...);
wins.someOtherTab = window.open(...);
```

Then to access global variables in that tab:

```
wins.someTab.someVar
```

And from inside that sub-tab:

```
opener.wins.someOtherTab.anotherVar
```